# Create an object type that uses an object's values as the key in the typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am creating a function called `formatAddress` which accepts an address object and property map object as input and outputs the mapped address.

```js
function formatAddress(address, map): MappedAddressOutput {
   ...
}

type MappedAddressOutput = AnyObject[typeof AddressMap[keyof typeof AddressMap]];

interface Address {
    addressLine1: string;
    addressLine2: string;
    city: string;
    province: string;
    postalCode: string;
}

const AddressMap = {
    addressLine1: "address1",
    addressLine2: "address2",
    city: "city",
    province: "province",
    postalCode: "postalCode"
};
type IndexSignature = string | number | symbol; 
type AnyObject = { [key: IndexSignature]: any };
```

If I wish to transform the `MappedAddressOutput` as the code below:

`type MappedAddressOutput = ObjectValueAsKey<AddressMap>`

How can I implement ObjectValueAsKey type?

Comment: I dont understand what do you trying to achieve with `formatAddress` function. Could you be more precise pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic type parameter so you can use the given map in the return type:

```
function formatAddress<To extends Record<keyof Address, string>>(address: Address, map: To): {
    [K in keyof Address as To[K]]: Address[K];
} {
    return Object.entries(address).map(([k, v]) => [map[k as keyof typeof map], v]);
}
```

Then when you use it, you have to make sure the map is inferred literally. The simplest way to do that is to use `as const`:

```
interface Address {
    addressLine1: string;
    addressLine2: string;
    city: string;
    province: string;
    postalCode: string;
}

const exampleMap = {
    addressLine1: "address1",
    addressLine2: "address2",
    city: "city",
    province: "province",
    postalCode: "postalCode"
} as const;

const result = formatAddress({
    addressLine1: "",
    addressLine2: "",
    city: "",
    province: "",
    postalCode: "",
}, exampleMap);
```

and now the type of `result` is

```
{
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    city: string;
    province: string;
    postalCode: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj1P6W)

Comment: `Type 'any[][]' is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof Address as To[K]]: Address[K]; }'.` anyhelp with this for latest ts